# Python3 I try to install lshash 0.0.4dev on windows 10

Tags: pip

I am trying to install lshash 0.0.4dev 
with pip install lshash on anconda promot
and I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTNHV.png)

```
(base) C:\Users\User>python -m pip install lshash
Collecting lshash
  Using cached lshash-0.0.4dev.tar.gz (7.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\\lshash\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\\lshash\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\lshash\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\lshash\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\lshash\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import lshash
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\lshash\lshash\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from lshash import LSHash
    ImportError: cannot import name 'LSHash' from 'lshash' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xq8e0vo7\lshash\lshash\__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Thank you!! 
i need the function LSHash
Does it exist in lshash3

Answer (score 0):

[`lshash` 0.0.4dev](https://pypi.org/project/lshash/0.0.4dev/) was released on Apr 27, 2013. The project seems to be abandoned at the very early stage of development. The code is obviously Python2-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing lshash3 instead

https://pypi.org/project/lshash3/

Comment: I installed lshash3 
and I can't run
" from lshash import LSHash"
i accept:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-84dc51539e06> in <module>
     ----> 7 from lshash import LSHash
  
~\Documents\foundMe\lshash.py in <module>
     10 import scipy.spatial.distance as dist
---> 12 from storage import storage
    
     14 try:

ImportError: cannot import name 'storage' from 'storage' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\storage\__init__.py)